# Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Post' when type checking Prisma fails

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, next.js13

I have created my Prisma PostgreSQL database with table Post. Now, I am creating an API file to be able to fetch the data from my database inside Next js 13's folder **"pages/api"** and named the file **getPosts.ts**

I have defined the type **Post** and the and included it to the **NextApiResponse** like so.

The problem is the returned json data doesn't use the type even when applied. it instead shows data as **"any"**. on the error too.

This is the **schema.prisma** table:

```
model Post {
  id        Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title     String
  image     String?
  content   String?
  published Boolean @default(false)
}
```

This is my **pages/api/getPosts.ts** which returns this error/warning:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import prisma from "@prisma/client";

type Post = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  image?: string;
  content?: string;
  published: boolean;
};

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Post> // <= The Type.
) {
  // Get Prisma to fetch the posts
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    try {
      const data = await prisma.post.findMany();
      return res.status(200).json(data); // Shows any?
    } catch (error) {
      return res.status(500).json(error); // Shows any?
    }
  }
}
```

How can I pass the correct types to the data?

Comment: Where exactly should the type Post occur? Can you mark it in your code?

Comment: Can you pass Post to findMany() like so: `findMany<Post>()`?

Comment: I get the following `Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.ts(2347)`

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with Prisma, but from my understanding of the docs, prisma generates the types from the model in a *.d.ts file: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#type-definitions